# Cron job to store content of iframe to a file that can be served with a php include

Tags: php, html, iframe, cron

Is it possible to set up a cron job to download the content of an iframe (the iframe loads into my website currently, content is served from another website) and cache it to a php file (or another file like HTML etc) so I can serve the content without it having to reload on every page refresh etc and without actually using the iframe in my website.

If not a cron job just something similar, a server process so the content is already cached on the server daily without it having to load from another site when a visitor loads the page.

Comment: The iframe has a URL. Use wget to pull the URL to a text file. Then, you have the source of the iframe in a text file. What you want to do with it from that point on is up to you.

Comment: Hi, can wget be set up to work as a daily server side process (as in automated) like a cron job? Also my hosting account might now allow me to add additional software to the web server, would that be needed for wget? Thanks

Comment: wget is standard on most linux servers. cron should be on it also. So, you would make a cron job to run wget just as you would any command you want to run repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks it will no doubt turn out that my 1and1 account doesn't even allow me to do cron jobs without upgrading to some uber package, but much appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to be a help vampire, but I think it will take me about a week to work out how to code this. I have confirmed I have ability to set up cron jobs. Would you like to write the code for me and I will paypal you for the time?

Comment: Assuming you don't know how to set up cron jobs, see this. It uses wget as the example command to run in the cron job. https://www.drupal.org/node/23714